# Why subsequence $ a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )} $ doesn't converge to $ b $ if its indexes depend on $ \epsilon $?

Tags: real-analysis

**Lemma used for proof of a theorem:**
$ L \in \mathbb{R} $ is a partial limit of sequence $ ( a_n ) $ **iff**  for all $ \epsilon > 0 $ the set $ \{ n : | a_n - L | < \epsilon \} $ is infinite.
**Notation**:  $ \mathscr{P}(a_n) $ is the set of all real partial limits of $ ( a_n) $
**Theorem**: Let $ ( a_n )  $ be a bounded sequence and let $ ( b_m) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(a_n)$ be a sequence of partial limits of $ ( a_n) $ s.t. $ \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} b_m = b$ .
Show that $ b \in \mathscr{P}(a_n)  $.
**Proof( from class notes )** :  We have $ \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} b_m = b$, therefore for every $ \epsilon > 0 $ there exists $ b_{k(\epsilon)} $ s.t. $ | b_{k(\epsilon)} - b | < \epsilon/2 $ ( since  $ 
\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists an index $k(\epsilon) $ s.t. $ \forall n>k(\epsilon) . $   $| b_n - b | < \epsilon $ , and I just chose one such index ), on the other hand $ b_{k(\epsilon)} \in \mathscr{P}(a_n)  $ ( meaning that $ b_{k(\epsilon)} $ is a partial limit ) so therefore there exists a subsequence $ a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )} $ s.t. $ a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )}  \xrightarrow{ p \to \infty }  b_{k(\epsilon)} $ , therefore there exists $ p_{0(k ( \epsilon) )} \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t.  for all $ p > p_{0(k ( \epsilon) )}  $ we have $  | a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )}  - b_{k(\epsilon)} | < \epsilon/2  $.
So for all $ p > p_{0(k ( \epsilon) )}  $ we have $ | a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )}  - b | \leq | a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )}  - b_{k(\epsilon)} | + | b_{k(\epsilon)} - b | < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon  $, meaning the set $ \{ n : | a_n - L | < \epsilon \} $ is infinite and therefore $ b \in \mathscr{P}(a_n)  $ . Q.E.D.
**My question**:
at the last steps of the proof, we got " $ p > p_{0(k ( \epsilon) )}. | a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )}  - b | < \epsilon  $  " and my professor said that it is false to think that we got here a subsequence $ a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )} $ that converges to $ b$ and that is because the indexes in a subsequence that converges to $ b $ should not depend on $ \epsilon $ ( And in $ a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )} $ the indexes $ n_{p}( k (\epsilon) ) $ depend on $ \epsilon $  ).
So I didn't really understand this *( I asked him for further clarification but the answer was overall the same and I still didn't understand. )*, why the subsequence  $ a_{n_{p}( k (\epsilon) )} $ does not converge to $ b $? so what if the indexes depend on $ \epsilon $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ where
\begin{aligned}
a_n=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }n \neq p^k \text{ for some prime } p,\, k \in \mathbb{N}\\
p^{-1}-k^{-\frac{p+1}{p}} & \text{if }n = p^k \text{ for some prime } p,\, k \in \mathbb{N}\end{cases}
\end{aligned}

So $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{p^k}=\lim_{k \to \infty} p^{-1}-k^{-\frac{p+1}{p}}=p^{-1}$ and $\lim_{m \to \infty} p_m^{-1}=0$ where $p_m$ denotes the $m$th prime number. Think about what issue might arise in applying your argument to the above example.

**Edit:**
I am annoyed by my first counterexample, so I want to also consider the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ where
\begin{aligned}
b_n=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }n \neq p^k \text{ for some prime } p,\, k \in \mathbb{N}\\
p^{-1}-pk^{-\frac{p+1}{p}} & \text{if }n = p^k \text{ for some prime } p,\, k \in \mathbb{N}\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
(I would like to think that there are in some sense better counterexamples to illustrate the problem with the proposed argument but I am a one mediocre idea kind of guy)

Comment: $ \mathscr{P}(a_n) = \{ 0,1,p_1^{-1},p_2^{-1},p_3^{-1},... \} $.  We have
$ ( p_m^{-1}) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(a_n)  $ . We have $ \lim_{m \to \infty} p_m^{-1}=0 $. Therefore $ \forall \epsilon>0 \exists p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1} $ s.t. $ | p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1} | < \epsilon/2 $. Since $ p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1} \in \mathscr{P}(a_n)  $. Therefore there exists a subsequence $ a_{p_{k(\epsilon)}^{k}} = p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1}-k^{-\frac{p_{k(\epsilon)}+1}{p_{k(\epsilon)}}} $ s.t. $ \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{p_{k(\epsilon)}^k}= p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1} $

Comment: therefore $ \exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall k>k_0. | a_{p_{k(\epsilon)}^k}  | < \epsilon/2   $.
Hence $ \forall k>k_0 $ $ | a_{p_{k(\epsilon)}^k}  | = | a_{p_{k(\epsilon)}^k} - p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1} + p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1}  | \leq | a_{p_{k(\epsilon)}^k} - p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1} | + | p_{k(\epsilon)}^{-1} |   < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon $             . I don't really see the issue, can you please elaborate?

Comment: The issue with your original argument lies in how for each subsequential limit you apply the definition of convergence to a subsequence that converges to a given partial limit of which your comments above have managed to ignore in responding to my answer.

Comment: So for a given $p$, how do you choose $K_p$ so that $| a_{p^k} - p^{-1}|=k^{-\frac{p+1}{p}}< \epsilon/2$ whenever $k \geq K_p$? What about for a prime $q$ such that $p>q$, will the same statement hold if we replace $p$ by $q$ or could we have $K_q > K_p$ . How can we take $\max\{K_p: p \text{ is a prime} \}$ if we have to have $K_q > K_p$ whenever $q>p$?? This is the issue. Look at the definition of convergent sequence. Given $\epsilon>0$, we need to show that there is some positive integer (FINITE NUMBER) such that blah blah happens.

Comment: How to correctly show $b \in \mathcal{P}(a_n)$: Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. There is $M \in \mathbb{N}$  so that $|b_m-b|<\epsilon/2$ whenever $m \geq M$. Since $b_M \in \mathcal{P}(a_n)$, we know that $\{n: |a_n-b_M|<\epsilon/2\}$ is infinite. Now notice that we have  $\{n: |a_n-b_M|<\epsilon/2\} \subseteq \{n: |a_n-b|<\epsilon\}$. Therefore $\{n: |a_n-b|<\epsilon\}$ is infinite.
**Edit to my previous comment: "...prime $q$ such that $q>p$*,..."**